# Android Sharedpreference went wrong

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my android app I am getting details of user in sharedpreference and calculated in another activity and displaying the result... but the result is showing error somehwere..

I am attaching the code below.

MainActivity:

```
String firstName     = et1.getText().toString();
        String middleName    = et2.getText().toString();
        String lastName      = et3.getText().toString();
        String callFirstName = et4.getText().toString();
        String callMiddleName = et5.getText().toString();
        String callLastName = et6.getText().toString();
        String dates         = et7.getText().toString();
        String months        = et8.getText().toString();
        String years         = et9.getText().toString();

else
        {   

             SharedPreferences setting = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editors = setting.edit();
             editors.putString("log", "log");


                editors.putString("fn", firstName);
                editors.putString("mn",middleName);
                editors.putString("ln",lastName);
                editors.putString("cfn",callFirstName);
                editors.putString("cmn", callMiddleName);
                editors.putString("cln",callLastName);
                editors.putString("dt",dates);
                editors.putString("mt",months);
                editors.putString("yrs",years);

                editors.commit();



            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
```

tablayoutActivity:

```
if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
       {

            firstN = String.valueOf(setting.getString("fn","not found"));
            middleN= String.valueOf(setting.getString("mn","not found"));
            lastN = String.valueOf(setting.getString("ln","not found"));
            callMN = String.valueOf(setting.getString("cmn","not found"));
            callLN= String.valueOf(setting.getString("cln","not found"));
            callFN = String.valueOf(setting.getString("cfn","not found"));
            daY = String.valueOf(setting.getString("dt","not found"));
            montH= String.valueOf(setting.getString("mt","not found"));
            yeaR = String.valueOf(setting.getString("yrs","not found"));


            int yearat =0;
            int monthat = 0;
            int dayat = 0;

            ch   = 0;
            ch1  = 0;
            ch2  = 0;
            ch3  = 0;
            ch4  = 0;
            pin  = 0;
            pin1 = 0;
            pin2 = 0;
            pin3 = 0;
            pin4 = 0; 

            sum11 = 0;
            sum19 = 0;
            sum18 = 0;
            sum20 = 0;
            sum70 = 0;
            sum80 = 0; 
            sum90 = 0;




            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            yearstr = Integer.toString(yearat);
            monthat = gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            monthstr = Integer.toString(monthat);
            dayat = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            daystr = Integer.toString(dayat);

            int day1 = Integer.parseInt(daY);
            int month1 = Integer.parseInt(montH);
            int year1 = Integer.parseInt(yeaR);



           String s1 = String.valueOf(TabLayoutActivity.this.getAge(year1, month1, day1));



            sum11 = getSum11((daY) + (montH) + (yeaR));
            sum18 = getSum18((yearstr) + (daY + montH));
            sum19 = getSum19((monthstr) + (sum18));
            sum20 = getSum20((daystr) + sum19);

            sum70 = getsum70(daY);
            sum80 = getSum80(montH);
            sum90 = getSum90(yeaR);


            int val      = 0;
            long val1    = sum11;
            //long val   = sum16;
            val          = Integer.valueOf(s1);
            long val2    = 36 - val1;
            int val4     = 9;           
            long val5    = val2 + val4;
            long val6    = val5 + val4;
            long val7    = val6 + 80;

            if (sum70 > sum80)
            {
                ch1 = (sum70 - sum80);
            }
            else
            {
                ch1 = (sum80 - sum70);
            }

            if (sum70 > sum90)
            {
                ch2 = (sum70 - sum90);
            }
            else
            {
                ch2 = (sum90 - sum70);
            }

            if (sum80 > sum90)
            {
                ch4 = (sum80 - sum90);
            }
            else
            {
                ch4 = (sum90 - sum80);
            }


            if (ch1 > ch2)
            {
                ch3 = ch1 - ch2;
            }
            else
            {
                ch3 = ch2 - ch1;
            }



            if (val <= val2)
            {
                ch = ch1;
            }


            else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
            {
                ch = ch2;
            }

            else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
            {
                ch = ch3;
            }

            else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
            {
                ch = ch4;
            }


            /*if (val <= val2)
            {
                pin = pin1;
            }


            else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
            {
                pin = pin2;
            }

            else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
            {
                pin = pin3;
            }

            else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
            {
                pin = pin4;
            }*/


            pyear            = String.valueOf(sum18);
            pmonth           = String.valueOf(sum19);
            pday             = String.valueOf(sum20);
            chn              = String.valueOf(ch);
            pinn             = String.valueOf(pin);

            yearstring       = yearstr;
            monthstring      = monthstr;
            daystring        = daystr;
            ms               = getCalc(monthstring);




       }

    //calculating single value of year
    private long getSum90(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum90 = 0;
        char[] name90 = new char[text.length()];
               name90 = text.toCharArray();               
               for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
               {
                   sum90 += value18( name90[i] );
                }
                 //while (sum10>9)               
              while (sum90>9 )
               {                     
                   sum90 = findDigitSum90(sum90);                 
               }
        return sum90;
    }

    private long findDigitSum90(long n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum90=0;
        while (n != 0) 
        {
         sum90 += n % 10;
         n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum90;
    }
    //calculate single value month
    private long getSum80(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum80 = 0;
        char[] name80 = new char[text.length()];
               name80 = text.toCharArray();               
               for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
               {
                   sum80 += value18( name80[i] );
                }
                 //while (sum10>9)               
              while (sum80>9 )
               {             
                   sum80 = findDigitSum80(sum80);                 
               }
        return sum80;
    }
```

logcat:

```
01-27 09:05:08.421: I/Choreographer(5431): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-27 09:05:10.792: D/dalvikvm(5431): GC_CONCURRENT freed 112K, 8% free 2688K/2920K, paused 9ms+432ms, total 1177ms
01-27 09:05:11.771: D/AndroidRuntime(5431): Shutting down VM
01-27 09:05:11.771: W/dalvikvm(5431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.numero/com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "not found"
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "not found"
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:83)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-27 09:05:12.371: E/AndroidRuntime(5431):     ... 11 more
01-27 09:10:13.672: I/Process(5431): Sending signal. PID: 5431 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post entire tablayoutactivity

Comment: could you please tell me what is the code at line 83 in TabLayoutActivity

Comment: int day1 = Integer.parseInt(daY);

Comment: the above line is line number 83

Comment: the log cat says there is error with value of function your setting string value in share preferences and converting it in to again string do look at it

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this:

```
daY = String.valueOf(setting.getString("dt","not found"));
```

And then later:

```
int day1 = Integer.parseInt(daY);
```

You cannot turn "not found" into an integer.

Edit:

You could use this function to determine whether the value is a String, before working further along the function. Or use this point to provide a default value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

clearly  problem is here:

```
 daY = String.valueOf(setting.getString("dt","not found"));
            montH= String.valueOf(setting.getString("mt","not found"));
            yeaR = String.valueOf(setting.getString("yrs","not found"));
```

The default value you are returning from preference is "not found" for  day, year and month, which is a string and later when the values are not found from preference you are  trying to convert string to number.

```
int year1 = Integer.parseInt(yeaR);
```

you should return instead some integer in these case.

setting.getString("yrs","1980")

Answer (score 1):

Replace 0 with `MODE_PRIVATE`

```
SharedPreferences setting = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line

```
  String dates = et7.getText().toString();
```

What input are you giving, if it's like

```
 27/01/2014 or 27-01-2014
```

problem is /,- cannot parse as Integer

**NEXT STEP :**

Default value ""

```
        daY = String.valueOf(setting.getString("dt",""));
        montH= String.valueOf(setting.getString("mt",""));
        yeaR = String.valueOf(setting.getString("yrs",""));
```

validation -

```
        if(daY.length() > 0)
          int dd = Integer.parseInt(daY);
```

Comment: no here.. user's date of birth is selected.. I mean in dates integer value of day is selected.. 1 - 31 and in months month value is selected 1-12 and in years 1967 like value is giving